# Create pretty url from plain html page?

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url, clean-urls, pretty-urls

I have looked over several articles on setting up "Pretty URL's" and I can't seem to get anything to work for me. I am new to the whole .htaccess process and it seems like everything I've seen is geared toward dynamic, .PHP based sites. Here is what I would like to see happen:

Ugly URL: http://www.example.com/test.html
Pretty URL: http://www.example.com/test/

What it am currently trying to use in the .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.html
```

Thus far, I've had no luck. I am not using any form of .php on the page - these are static .html pages. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9309380/139010

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I gave the solution the page a shot (and just changed this line:

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I gave the solution the page a shot (and just changed this line: 

RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html http://www.quotist.com/$1/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

Same 500 error message.

Here is the new .htaccess code I am using:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(letter)=(\w)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html http://www.igeniusstore.com/$1/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([\w-]+)/(letter)/\w/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html?%2=%3 [L,QSA]

Comment: I even tried this basic code and still cannot get it to work:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^this-test/?$     test.html      [NC,L]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured out what issue was. My compiler was corrupting the .htaccess file, which was triggering the site-wide error message on load. You can see that it's working now here:

http://www.igeniusstore.com/this-test.html

or

http://www.igeniusstore.com/this-test

Here's the basic code that I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Thanks for all of your help. Cheers!